# Is V616 Monocerotis the closest black hole?

Tags: black-hole, distances

Now that HR 6819 has been found not to be a black hole after all, does that currently leave V616 Monocerotis as the closest known stellar mass black hole?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nearest_known_black_holes

Comment: Feel free to self answer.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: It means that you have now done some research and you have found the answer to your question.  You can write an answer to your question (as an answer) and if it is good I can upvote your answer.  You don't need to leave this question unanswered. You are encouraged to write answers to your own questions, when you have found the answer to them.

Comment: I see. Well, from the Wiki article, which appears to be well documented and presumably up to date, V616 Monocerotis is the closest confirmed black hole. 

V Puppis is closer, at roughly 960 light-years, but it's not confirmed. So that would be the closest black hole candidate.

I note that distances cited for V616 are uncertain. This list has it at "3000±300." I see various figures elsewhere ranging from 3,300 ly to 4,700 ly. But even so, there is nothing estimated to be closer.

Answer (score 4):

V616 Monocerotis is the closest confirmed black hole.
([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nearest_known_black_holes))

V Puppis is closer, at roughly 960 light-years, but it's not confirmed. So that would be the closest black hole candidate.

Distances cited for V616 are uncertain. This list has it at "3000±300." I see various figures elsewhere ranging from 3,300 ly to 4,700 ly. But even so, there is nothing estimated to be closer.